# GNU AGPL v3 запрещает установить рекламу AdSense?

Tags: лицензирование, google-adsense

Есть OpenSource проект с лицензией: GNU AFFERO GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE

Вопрос в том, если я поставлю рекламу от Google AdSense (или любую другую рекламу), буду нарушать закон (лицензию)?

Comment: Мало информации. Что представляет из себя проект? В каком виде вы собираетесь линковать AdSense?

Comment: https://github.com/ornicar/lila

Comment: это сайт где можно играть в шахматы онлайн, собирался ставить рекламу где-то на странице, думаю это не так важно

Comment: Моё мнение (не обязательно полностью корректное :)): Если вашего кода на сайте не будет, вы нарушите лицензию. Если же будет ваш дизайн, ваш код, то в куски вашего кода, думаю, можно вставить рекламу.

Comment: интересно было бы узнать точно, спросил в issue и мне ответили что рекламу нельзя ставить, хотя странно, нашёл в сети информацию что можно https://github.com/ornicar/lila/issues/5527#event-2640594334

Comment: Ни одна из лицензий GNU не запрещает коммерческое использование. Нарушением будет ваш отказ предоставить модифицированные вами исходники

Comment: Я тоже так знал, странно что разработчики ответили что это будет нарушением :)

Comment: не очень понял, можете объяснить подробнее?

Comment: Перенес часть комментарив в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни одна из лицензий GNU не запрещает коммерческое использование.

Но применительно к указанному вами проекту [вам ответили](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/issues/5527#issuecomment-531789449)

> As far as I can tell you won't be able to license the adsense code under the AGPL, so including it would indeed be a license violation.

Перевод близко к тексту

> Насколько могу судить, вы не можете перелицензировать код AdSense под AGPL, значит его включение будет нарушением лицензии.

Если я правильно понимаю, для интеграции с AdSense нужно добавить в свой проект некоторый код от Google (если это не так, то описанное далее не имеет значения).

Чтобы два куска кода разных авторов можно было объединить в один проект, лицензии обоих кусков должны это допускать.

Все лицензии GNU являются "вирусными", т.е. требуют чтобы итоговый проект был под той же самое лицензией GNU (или более сильной из двух, если обе GNU)

Значит чтобы это сделать лицензия на второй кусок кода должна быть AGPL-совместимой.

Google же AGPL очень не любит, о чем открыто заявляет. Все их библиотеки на GitHub для интеграции с AdSense выложены под AGPL-несовместимой APL v2

Comment: Я в свой проект использую и Google Analytics и Яндекс.Метрику. Получаеться что это тоже наружение? И получаеться что нарушаю права Google, а не права ornicar, да?

Comment: Google AdSense выдаёт кусок кода, один скрипт который нужно вставить на страницу, и всё. Может если этот кусок кода переписать тогда нарушение не будет?

Comment: Тогда бы нельзя было бы использовать GNU-скрипты в сервлетах и апплетах. На мой взгляд, нужно сделать разграничение кода и в своём коде уже использовать рекламу

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear, судя по тому, что на GitHub есть AGPLv3 проекты с AdSense, переписывание действительно поможет.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, а те самые GNU-скрипты под какой лицензией: GPL, AGPL или LGPL? Это сильно меняет дело

Comment: >> на GitHub есть AGPLv3 проекты с AdSense
@ГерманБорисов а можете поделиться ссылкой на такие проекты?

Comment: Вот, например, модуль для OpenSource социальной сети https://github.com/GreenMeteor/humhub-adsense-module